# Error when trying to add OpenBLAS dependency twice: via add_subdirectory and find_package at the same time

Tags: c++, cmake, openblas

I am making use of `OpenBLAS` for both my `BLAS` and `LAPACK` routine calls. I do not want the user base of my `C++` library to have to install the dependency on their machine. So I want to supply the `OpenBLAS` library in my `third_party` and have `CMake` link to it locally.

### The tree

This is the tree of this minimal example project.

```
OBLASCmake/
├─ third_party/
│  ├─ OpenBLAS-0.3.15
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ main.cpp
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

extern "C" double ddot_(int *n, double *x, int *incx, double *y, int * incy);

int main() {
    int n = 3;  // n elements
    vector<double> x = {1.2, 2.4, 3.8};
    vector<double> y = {4.8, 5.5, 6.2};
    int incx = 1;  // increments
    int incy = 1;

    double dot_product = ddot_(&n, &*x.begin(), &incx, &*y.begin(), &incy);

    std::cout << dot_product << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### CMakeLists (currently)

This goes into the system and looks for the `OpenBLAS` installation on the users machine. This is not what I want, but it works for me because I have it installed on my machine.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(OBLASCMake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(OBLASCMake SHARED main.cpp)
set(BLA_VENDOR OpenBLAS)
find_package(BLAS)
if (BLAS_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(OBLASCMake ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})
else()
    # ERROR
endif()

add_executable(test1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 OBLASCMake)
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME RunTest COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1)
```

The result of running the test with this cmake is an output of `42.52` as the dot product of the two vectors.

#### CMakeLists (what I want)

This method of defining the local installation is not working properly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(OBLASCMake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(OBLASCMake SHARED main.cpp)
# cant use add_subdirectory and find_package
# add_subdirectory(third_party/OpenBLAS-0.3.15)
set(OpenBLAS_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/OpenBLAS-0.3.15)
find_package(OpenBLAS REQUIRED HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/OpenBLAS-0.3.15)

add_executable(test1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test1 OBLASCMake)
enable_testing()
add_test(NAME RunTest COMMAND ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test1)
```

Building with CMake results in the following error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenBLAS" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenBLASConfig.cmake
    openblas-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenBLAS" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenBLAS_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "OpenBLAS" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

There is an `OpenBLASConfig.cmake` file in the `third_party/OpenBLAS-0.3.15/`, but CMake isn't seeing it. Does anyone know why cmake is unable to see the config file?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not cmake expert, but maybe you have to use the absolute path, like `set(OpenBLAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR_ALWAYS_FORGET_EXACT_NAME}/third_party/OpenBLAS-0.3.15")`

Comment: You don't use `add_subdirectory` _and_ `find_package` for the same dependency. Pick one.

Comment: I have updated based on the previous two comments. Still getting the same error message @AlexReinking

Comment: @GeneralCode well, do what you did also for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are defining `OpenBLAS_DIR` without actually using it in the `find_package` call (which probably takes an absolute `PATH` or `HINT`).